Why the low 16 bits of sizeCtl calculates the number of threads from 1 rather than 0 in ConcurrentHashMap？
When I read the source code of ConcurrentHashMap in Java 8, I learned that it uses the field sizeCtl to control initialization and resizing: -1 is for initialization and other negative is for resizing. It will use U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2) to set sizeCtl when trying to resize. The high 16 bits are a stamp rs generated by resizeStamp(n) which forces top bit to 1 to ensure it's negative after left shift, and the low 16 bits is one plus the number of threads trying resizing.
I don't understand why the low 16 bits calculates the number of threads from 1 rather than 0. I read some articles explaining that it remains for the number -1 to indicate initialization. But as far as I know, the binary of -1 is 11111111111111111111111111111111, so remaining 0000000000000001 in low 16 bits can't be useful for it. How to explain it?
if (check >= 0) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab, nt; int n, sc;
    while (s >= (long)(sc = sizeCtl) && (tab = table) != null &&
           (n = tab.length) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        int rs = resizeStamp(n);
        if (sc < 0) {
            if ((sc >>> RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) != rs || sc == rs + 1 ||
                sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || (nt = nextTable) == null ||
                transferIndex <= 0)
                break;
            if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                transfer(tab, nt);
        }
        else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,
                                     (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2))
            // Start resizing
            transfer(tab, null);
        s = sumCount();
    }
}

